# What is wrong with my chef config.json file?

Tags: json, chef-infra

This is my config.json file:

```
{
        "run_list": ["recipe[test]"]
}
```

and this is the error:

```
FATAL: Configuration error SyntaxError: config.json:2: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting tASSOC
    "run_list": ["recipe[test]"]
               ^
config.json:3: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting $end
[2014-04-28T12:22:01+02:00] FATAL: Aborting due to error in 'config.json'
```

why??? :(

Comment: Are you *sure* this is a json file, and not a ruby file? That's what the error seems to imply.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because your "json" is actually being parsed as Ruby:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> {
irb(main):002:1*         "run_list": ["recipe[test]"]
irb(main):003:1> }
SyntaxError: (irb):2: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting tASSOC
        "run_list": ["recipe[test]"]
                   ^
(irb):3: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting $end
```

So either a) find out why it's not being parsed as JSON.

or b) write your config in Ruby format:

```
{ "run_list" => ["recipe[test]"] }

# or 

{ run_list: ["recipe[test]"] }
```

or c) convert the json string to Ruby:

```
require 'json'
JSON.parse('{ "run_list": ["recipe[test]"] }')

=> {"run_list"=>["recipe[test]"]}
```

Comment: how can i change that?

Answer (score 0):

I had this error to. For me I had to change my from from `myRole.rb` to `myRole.json` (using `mv myRole.rb myRole.json`) and then did `knife role from file myRole.json` and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem myself and after a lot of looking around for answers I realized I was having the problem because I was using the `-f` flag instead of `j`. The command should look like this:

`$ chef-client -j <file>.json`